# Google Sheets Filtering by 2 separate conditions

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, filtering, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a way to most effectively see who is working at a certain day and block of time. So far, I've created my data lists that have the Name of the reps in A, the day available in B, the reps names again in D, and the blocks of time available in E. I've been trying to use FILTER in order for it to pull based on 2 dropdowns. I've tried using all 3 of these:

```
=filter(Sheet2!A2:A999,Sheet2!B2:B999=A2,Sheet2!E2:E999=B2) 

=FILTER(Sheet2!A2:A,(Sheet2!B1:b=A2)+(Sheet2!B2:B=B2)

=Filter(Filter(Sheet2!A2:A999, Sheet2!B2:B999=A2), Sheet2!B2:B999=B2)
```

But I can't crack it. The last nested formula seems like it's functioning correctly, except that it's returning a different number of rows each time, so I don't know how to avoid the mismatched range error it gets. To be fair, I'm basically trying to create this from scratch, having known nothing about the FILTER function before saturday. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this with filters would be super helpful.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WhBSQy4OZFtJvheNHd5ZfIRvcDxvUb-WhdY0mUci3O0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you please make the sheet "editable" so that people can help on the sheet itself?

Answer (score 0):

first, in your data validation fix `7-7:30` to `7-730`. then use this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(QUERY(TO_TEXT({Sheet2!A2:B; Sheet2!D2:E}), 
 "select Col1 where Col2 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A2:B2)&"'")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Unfortunately, that  is filtering based on the day, but not the block of time. But it does give me a better sense of the QUERY function, so I can play more with that.

Comment: I did get this to work on a separate set of test data that was much simplified, so I will rework my data from the big sheet and update, thanks!

Comment: I reworked all of my data to make sure it was uniform, and matched the data validation, and it's only filtering by time, and not day (For instance, If I select tuesday at 10, Taylor Hudson shows up even though I don't work tuesdays, and there is no Tuesday datapoint near my name.) I'm obviously doing something wrong, I just can't figure out what that is.

Comment: Now it's filtering by day, but not by time. For instance, Sara Sikra is in at 11, but it shows her at 6. I wonder if I can just compare the results from those 2 columns of results, and remove the non duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

I have found this function `=filter(Sheet2!A2:A136, Sheet2!B2:B136 =G2)` on your sheet and based on that I have added the filter for the time, and works.

The working condition is:

```
=filter(Sheet2!A2:A136, Sheet2!B2:B136 =A2, Sheet2!E2:E136 = B2)
```

Based on the [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) documentation:

> FILTER(range, condition1, [condition2, ...])

Comment: When I plug that in, it comes up with a "no matches found in FILTER" error. I may just have entered some data incorrectly, so I'll test this further.

Comment: This error appears when there is no data on the timeblock you have chosen. I have tried Monday -> 730-8 for example and the results are Ne'Keya Esteen, Dustin Hernandez and Michael Schafer

Comment: Interesting. There are definitely more results for that day and time than are coming up, but I think it may be a data entry issue from me.